# ¿Se puede instalar Laravel en un hosting compartido?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, aplicación-web, servidor

Voy a empezar a desarrollar un proyecto pero tengo gran una duda,¿Se puede instalar laravel en un hosting compartido? ¿Puedo ver los errores en linea y trabajar directamente? he investigado acerca de Laravel y veo que se utiliza Compoiser para instalar librerias, pero al ser un hosting compartido y al ser subido al servidor es posible que genere conflictos?

Answer (score 5):

Sí se puede instalar en un hosting compartido, ya he instalado varios proyectos así:

1. Instala todas las dependencias en tu servidor local o de desarrollo.
2. Carga todos los archivos de tu proyecto al servidor (incluyendo la carpeta vendor), dejando en tu directorio público del servidor únicamente el contenido del directorio **public**.
3. El resto de archivos los puedes/debes ubicar en una carpeta FUERA del sitio público, por seguridad.
4. En el archivo index.php de tu carpeta **public**, modifica las siguientes variables para que encuentren los puntos de entrada de acuerdo a tu estructura de directorios:

   ```
   require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
   ```

Según el proveedor de hosting puede que te permita usar directamente o no Composer y artisan, esto ya deberás probarlo.

Answer (score 4):

Para la instalación de proyectos laravel en servidores compartidos esto es lo que hago:

## Prerequisitos:

- Acceso SSH a servidor compartido
- Tener tu proyecto en algun repositorio remoto GIT (github.com)
- Version de **PHP v7** o mayor

Luego de que tengas eso, ingresas por medio de SSH a tu servidor compartido.
te colocas en la raíz de tu usuario con `cd`.

Verificas que tengas *GIT, Composer* instalados en tu servidor. Esto lo puedes verificar con:

GIT

```
git --version
```

Composer

```
composer -v
```

> si no tienes instalado ninguno, o te falta alguno, [Instalar Composer por linea de comando](https://getcomposer.org/download/). Para GIT si tienes que solicitar que te lo instalen, ya que no puedes usar muchos de los comandos BASH. Como *apt-get, yum* entre otros.

Una vez tengas presente que tienes estos dos, solamente falta clonar tu repositorio con:

```
git clone https://url.de.tu.repositorio.git [nombre_de_carpeta_contenedora]
```

ingresas a tu carpeta creada con el clon de tu repositorio

```
cd [nombre_de_carpeta_contenedora]
```

Instalas todas las dependencias de tu instalación de laravel con

```
composer install
```

Con esto tu proyecto laravel instalará todas las dependencias necesarias.

Despues entras a la carpeta *public* de laravel

```
cd public
```

y copias todo el contenido de este directorio a tu carpeta publica de la url

```
cp -r ./ ../../nombre_de_carpeta_publica_de_tu_url
```

Esto copiara el index.php, y las carpetas publicas de tu proyecto. como los *JS/, css/, images/*, entre otros.

> Esto implica que cada vez que hagas una modificacion en estos archivos, usualemte inclusiones de **.js *.css imagenes* **Tienes como obligación hacer este proceso de nuevo**

Ahora bien ya copiaste los datos a la carpeta publica de tu url, debes ingresar a ella

```
cd
cd nombre_de_carpeta_publica_de_tu_url
```

Y aqui tienes que modificar el archivo index.php, ya que tiene unas rutas relativas a la inclusión de los archivos de arranque.

Colocando el comando

```
nano index.php
```

se abrira un editor de texto, buscaras la linea que dice algo como:
[image: index.php]

y modificas para que quede

```
require __DIR__.'/../carpeta_de_tu_proyecto_laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../carpeta_de_tu_proyecto_laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

> Recuerda que son **rutas relativas** si tienes otro sistema de archivos modifica según tus necesidades.

Con esto te debe salir tu proyecto de laravel con la url

> Recuerda que tienes que modificar tu archivo **.env** que ahora se llama **.env.example** porque clonaste tu repositorio, para que coloques todos los datos de configuración de tus bases de datos y demás.

## [Modificación 2017-10-11](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5)

Esta modificación es para **actualizar el directorio publico**, ya que cuando subimos una imagen o algun archivo, y lo guardamos en el directorio publico (carpeta *public*) lo guarda en el directorio publico de donde se coloco el proyecto, esto no indica que para cuando queramos acceder a estos recursos no estará en donde esta el *index.php* que modificamos para relacionarlo con el proyecto.
Esta actualización consiste en cambiar el public path justo despues de que cargue laravel.

1. Nos vamos posicionamos despues de cargar el **bootstrap/app.php** (linea ~38 del index.php)
2. colocamos la siguiente linea haciendo el mismo proceso de redirección con rutas relativas

`$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__.'/[ruta_relativa_hacia_el_directorio_publico]';
});`

De esta manera cuando coloques _public_path()_ indicaras que quieres acceder al directorio publico que esta a la vista de todos.

Comment: Requisitos: **PHP 7**. Sin Git ni SSH se puede instalar y mantener, eso si, lo complica.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí en esta página se explica muy bien como pudes instalar laravel dentro de un servidor compartido, es válido para la mayoria de los casos. Explica como instala [Como instalar Laravel en un servidor compartido](http://www.yoelprogramador.com/como-instalar-laravel-en-un-servidor-compartido/)
Espero que te sirva

Comment: Bienvenido/a a Stack Overflow en español! Aunque esto en teoría podría responder la pregunta, [sería preferible](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y dejar el vínculo como referencia.