# Error 500: Al subir sitio en Laravel a Hosting, ¿Como poner todo el proyecto en public_html?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, servidor

Contrate un servicio de Hosting (Donweb) con un plan inicial, El cual segun el soporte del proveedor, no me permite acceder a carpetas externas del public_html. Osea que todo mi proyecto tiene que estar contenido dentro de ella.

He visto varios videos, donde le cambian la direccion a los path dentro del index

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Pero lo hacen para poder entrar a un directorio padre. En mi caso tengo que hacer un cambio para que entre a una carpeta dentro del public_html

Tambien he visto que le modifican el .htacess pero la verdad es que no entiendo bien los cambios que tendria que hacer para mi caso. Lo dejo por las dudas

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Se puede instalar Laravel en un hosting compartido?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22056/se-puede-instalar-laravel-en-un-hosting-compartido)

Comment: Eso lo entendi perfectamente. Mas bien lo probe en hostinger en un servicio gratis y anduvo bien. Mi tema es que en este nuevo servicio q contrate aparentemente no me deja poner nada fuera de la carpeta public_html.  Es por eso que necesito tener el proyecto completo dentro de public_html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que si empiezas con `/` tu ruta será a partir de la raíz, en este caso es public_html y te da mas error si pones `/../` en todo caso te sugiero empezar con:

```
require __DIR__.'bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: a tu solucion si le tuve q agregar el primer slash. quedando asi: '/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php' (en mi caso cree una subcarpeta llamada laravel para mi proyecto)